# Android `@BindingAdapter` setter not being called

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my `BindingAdapter`:

```
public class Bindings{
    @BindingAdapter({"font"})
    public static void setFont(TextView textView, String fontName) {
        textView.setTypeface(FontCache.getInstance(textView.getContext()).get(fontName));
    }
}
```

*Instead of using "font" as the annotation parameter, I've tried "bind:font", "android:font", and "app:font", and made all the corresponding changes in the layout, but the `BindingAdapter` is still not called

Here is the layout where I use the `BindingAdapter` (bind_layout.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data></data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            font="@{`fontawesome-webfront`}"
            android:text="@string/double_left"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

*this layout is included in the Activity's layout which is set using `DatabindingUtils.setContentView`

Here is the activity whose layout includes bind_layout.xml:

```
public class ACreateSemester extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<CreateItemView> mCreateItemViews;
    private LinearLayout mItemContainer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.a_create_items);
        mItemContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.item_container);
        mItemContainer.addView(new CreateItemView(this, Item.getDefaultItem()));
    }

}
```

The three files I referenced here are listed in their entirety.

The way I know the `BindingAdapter` is not being called is because I set a breakpoint on the method and also in the body, and the breakpoint is never reached.

Any idea why the `BindingAdapter` is not firing?

Comment: Have you tried to put a breakpoint in the `setFont` method?

Comment: @Darwind yes sir. that's how i know it's not being called. made appropriate edits to relfect that.

Comment: tried: `@BindingAdapter({"bind:font"})` and `bind:font="@{'fontawesome-webfront'}"` ?

Comment: @pskink tried that. say that in the beginning of the question.

Comment: just for testing change `setFont` into `setFoooont` and check if gradle compiles your project, it should show an error about missing adapter

Comment: Ok, try to remove the `{}` around the attribute in the `BindingAdapter` annotation, so it looks like this: `@BindingAdapter("font")` instead.

Comment: @pskink that compiles correctly, but changing the name of the attribute in xml to "foooont" caused a data binding error `****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute app:foooont...`

Comment: @Darwind tried, but breakpoint is still not reached.

Comment: are you using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2` ?

Comment: @pskink no, 2.2.1.

Comment: Have you tried adding any variable inside the `<data>` node and then setting the object on the binding in code?

Comment: @Darwind no. all i'm doing is getting a `String` from the `font` attibute, and setting the typeface of the view according to whatever it is. there's no need to have variables inside `<data>`. as far as i know, having variables in `<data>` is optional.

Comment: I've noticed weird behaviours when not having a variable set and bound through code. Try it out and see if it does a difference. Even though the Databinding is actually in version 1.+ it still has some rough edges around.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did not found any solution

Answer (score 4):

Please, also make sure that you have made this steps.

1. Apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' in your app level build.gradle.
2. Set lifecycle owner to binding from your activity's onCreate() method e.g. 
       binding.lifecycleOwner = this, where this is your Activity.
3. Change font="@{`fontawesome-webfront`}" to app:font="@{`fontawesome-webfront`}"
   in your xml.
4. *Add some Id  to your button in xml layout.*

Answer (score 3):

I think you missed to connect your view with viewModel in activity.

```
public class ACreateSemester extends AppCompatActivity {
private List<CreateItemView> mCreateItemViews;
private LinearLayout mItemContainer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ACreateItemsBinding binding =  DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.a_create_items);
    mItemContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.item_container);
    mItemContainer.addView(new  CreateItemView(this,Item.getDefaultItem()));
    binding.setView(YourViewHere);
}
```